# i am getting this error when i try to define array of object with sequelize ORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

original: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[], `status` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'inComplete', `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `' at line 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dop52.png)

i am try to add array of obj
{
"userId":1,
"heading":"R8tr meeting",
"subHeading":[{
"title":"chat",
"status":false
},
{
"title":"jobs",
"status":false
}
]
}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.